# Bootstrap - gap between input text field and button

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

This my code http://jsbin.com/ixevaw/1/edit

```
<div class="input-append">
   <input type="search" class="span3" placeholder="Search" name="search" id="search"/>
   <button class="btn">button</button>
</div>
```

But there is a gap between text field and button in safari and IE9

How can i remove this gap?

Comment: Not seeing any gap in IE9 .. are you sure its not on compatibility mode?

Comment: Looks the same to me in both Safari and IE7/8/9.

Comment: I see the gap in Safari 5.1.7.

Comment: The gap appears on the Bootstrap demo page, too. http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a Bootstrap bug. You'd probably have to put a -5px left margin on the button for those browsers only using detection or alternate stylesheets.

```
.input-append input + .btn {margin-left: -5px;}
```

Answer (score 2):

Bizarrely, if you remove the space between the tags the problem goes away. So you want it to look like this:

```
<div class="input-append">
   <input type="search" class="span3" placeholder="Search" name="search" id="search"/><button class="btn">button</button>
</div>
```